# strange process names when trying to get a PID in rust with the Windows api

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

Hello my goal is to create a rust function which takes a process name as string and returns a PID.

I came up with this function:

```
pub unsafe fn get_proc_id(proc_name: String) -> u32 {
let mut proc_id: u32 = 0;
let mut h_snap = windows::Win32::System::Diagnostics::ToolHelp::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(
    TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS,
    0,
);
let h_snap = match h_snap {
    Ok(t) => t,
    Err(e) => panic!("eror {}", e),
};

let mut proc_entry: PROCESSENTRY32 = PROCESSENTRY32 {
    ..PROCESSENTRY32::default()
};

proc_entry.dwSize = std::mem::size_of::<PROCESSENTRY32>() as u32;
let entry_ptr = &mut proc_entry as *mut PROCESSENTRY32;

if windows::Win32::System::Diagnostics::ToolHelp::Process32First(h_snap, entry_ptr).as_bool() {
    loop {
        let mut proc_exe_string: String = String::new();

        if proc_exe_string.eq(&proc_name) {
            proc_id = proc_entry.th32ProcessID;
            break;
        }
        for e in proc_entry.szExeFile {
            if e.0 != 0 {
                proc_exe_string.push(e.0 as char)
            }
        }
        println!("{}", proc_exe_string);
        if !Process32Next(h_snap, entry_ptr).as_bool() {
            break;
        }
    }
}
CloseHandle(h_snap);
return proc_id; }
```

The function prints some strange process names. for example I'm looking for "ac_client.exe" however the function shows this process as ac_client.exeexe.exeee and this is similar for most process names. some other examples:
chrome.exexeexe.exeee
Discord.exer.exee.exee

Comment: Sounds like a problem with string length, perhaps length in bytes vs length in (unicode) characters?

Comment: I've never used `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`, but MSFT has this guide for enumerating processes from C++ that may be helpful to you.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes

Comment: You probably need to `break` when encountering a NULL character: `if e.0 == 0 { break; }`

Comment: I would probably do something like `let proc_exe_string = proc_entry.szExeFile.iter().take_while(|e| e.0 != 0).map(|e| e.0 as char).collect();`